# CGAffineTransformMakeScale and CoreGraphics

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, cgaffinetransform

I've got a UIView overriding the drawRect: method.

Now, when I'm doing

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(recognizer.scale,1.0);
```

everything scales; the view itself as well as everything drawn on it.

But now I would like to only scale specific things drawn on it. Is it possible to draw to e.g. draw to two different layers and then scale only one specific layer?

Unfortunately, it's no option to take different views - that's performing a lot worse, I tried... (large UIScrollView with view above it, draw in the view above scrollView - scrolling is slow then - but if I draw to the UIScrollView directly, it performs good).

Thanks a LOT!

**EDIT**
The second approach:
- UIWindow
-- UIView
--- UIScrollView <== this view should NOT resize in Transformation
---- UIView <== here, I draw some things on with CoreGraphics <== should be resized in Transformation

The view with core graphic objects on it has the same size as the UIScrollView.contentSize and always gets setNeedsDisplayInRect when the scrollview is scrolled... but for me, it's much slower...

Comment: Hard to believe the 2 view approach is slower. It should be a lot faster. Could it be that your implementation did unnecesarry redraws (e.g. Of the top view while scrolling)

Comment: @Kris: are we talking of the same thing? I adapted my post to clearify things...

Comment: Have you tried making that UIView a sibling of the scrollview, not a child (subview)?

Comment: no; because the objects in that view must be scrolled and resized in transformation - is that possible if the view is a sibling instead of a child? Don't I have to do all the scrolling/transformation by myself?